# Regex to find sentences starting and ending with

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writting a REGEX to find sentences starting with `_@_` and ending with `__d__`. `d` can be 1 or 2 digit.
For example, I have this expression

```
getting a regex _@_enter text  text . tex, text here__2___2_ te xt text .
```

and would like to get

```
_@_enter text  text . tex, text here__2__
```

Here is my try.

```
^(_@_)?.*\n\_\_\d{1,2}\_$/gm
```

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with this ?

Comment: [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) might be easier fwiw.

Comment: Your example suggests that you want to *extract* a pattern that can be *anywhere in the input*.
Your regex pattern however  `^(_@_)?.*\n\_\_\d{1,2}\_$` suggests that you want to match the *entire* input, from start (`^`) to finish (`$`). I guess that's where things went wrong? :)

Comment: Just to mention, if your sentences don't contain `@` or underscore, using [negation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) [`_@_[^@_]*__\d\d?__`](https://regex101.com/r/Sduosh/1) will be more efficient than [`.*?`](https://regex101.com/r/uo1Rsg/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
/(_@_)(.+?)(_\d{1,2}_)/gm
```

Comment: Maybe explain what you changed to solve the problem?

Comment: 1. \n - it's line-break, but in your example you don't need to check it  
2. you should use group for _2_

Comment: (I'm not the OP - just an interested 3rd-party)

Comment: Thank you @Sect0R. The expression can extend over 2 lines. That is why I would like to include the line-brake.

Comment: Use `/gm` modifier: `m` is multi-lines (js)

Comment: @Kyv Change `(.+?)` into `([\s\S]+?)`. JavaScript only recently adopted the `/s` modifier so I would hesitate to rely on `/gms`.

Answer (score 1):

If the match can be over 2 lines, you can optionally match the rest of the current line followed by a newline after matching `_@_`.

```
_@_(?:.*\n)?.*?__\d\d?__
```

**Explanation**

- `_@_` Match literally
- `(?:.*\n)?` Optionally match the rest of the line followed by a newline
- `.*?` Match any character except a newline, as few as possible
- `__\d\d?__` Match 1 or 2 digits between `__`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V5BSNL/1)

```js
const regex = /_@_(?:.*\n)?.*?__\d\d?__/g;
const str = `getting a regex _@_enter text  text . tex, text here__2___2_ te xt text .

getting a regex _@_enter text  text . 
tex, text here__3___3_ te xt text .


getting a regex _@_enter text  text . 

tex, text here__4___4_ te xt text .`;

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

A deviation from @Sect0R s answer that also matches sentences over multiple lines but doesn't need the s modifier:

```
(_@_)((?:.|\n)+?)(__\d{1,2}__)
```

(And it looks for two _ around the end-sentence-number.)